# make the Options of a Select smaller / very long text in the Options

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have been trying to control the length of an option when the text is very long and I would like the text to break a line when its content is greater than 300 pixels

**My code:**

```css
.form-control-select option {
  font-size: smaller !important;
  width: 300px !important;
  white-space: break-spaces !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important; //use this if you want to shorten
}

.form-control-select {
  max-width: 200px !important;
  white-space: break-spaces !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important; //use this if you want to shorten
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option style="width: 300px !important;" *ngFor="let item of Articulos_Select">
    {{ item.DESCRIPCION_INTERNA }}
  </option>
</select>
```